# Is-a relationship without virtual functions c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I couldn't find examples of is-a relationship without virtual functions. Is a following pattern ok?

```
class Base {
public:
  void doSomethingWithX() {/*implementation here*/}
protected:
  ~Base(){}
private:
   int x_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
//Add some other functionality but inherit doSomethingWithX and its implementaion
public: 
  void doSomethingWithY();
  ~Derived(); //And document that nobody should inherit further from this class.
private:
  int y_;
};

foo(Base* ptr) {
//Do something via Base interface
}

Derived d;
foo(&d);
```

Edit: I was asked to clarify what I mean by "is this pattern ok".
Does this kind of inheritance satisfies what is usually needed from is-a relationship? Liskov substitution principle etc.
Is it safe to use Derived objects via pointer to Base? (or I miss some problem here).

I'm asking this because there is often written that base class destructor should be either public and virtual or protected and non-virtual. But I never met real examples of public inheritance without non-virtual functions.

Comment: Define what do you mean by _Is a following pattern ok?_ Currently it's not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: This code will compile and you will be able to use `doSomethingWithX` inside `foo`.

Comment: Yes, it's okay. Dervied *is-a* Base. But it won't behave polymorphically.

Comment: _And document that nobody should inherit further from this class_ - is it documented bevause you have a destructor?

Comment: If nobody should inherit from `Derived`, then you can mark it [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) since C++11

Comment: @manni66, As `Derived` has public non-virtual destructor, it's dangerous do derive from it. Calling destructor on `Derived*` pointer than actually points to `DerivedFromDerived`will cause undefined behaviour. That's why destructor in `Base` is protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay *for what you're doing here*; You can pass a pointer to `Derived` and it can bind to a pointer of `Base` just fine. It's not possible to say whether it satisfies the Liskov subtitution principle because we do not know the invariants of your classes.

Just recognize that without any virtual functions, you cannot use polymorphism. This goes beyond simply overriding function behavior; you'll never be able to perform a `dynamic_cast` of a pointer to `Base` to a pointer to `Derived`.

Additionally, if nobody should derive from `Derived`, then mark it [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), which is available since C++11

Comment: _It's not possible to say whether it satisfies the Liskov subtitution principle because we do not know the invariants of your classes_ - It seems impossible for `Derived` to break any of `Base` invariants. No matter what I write in `Derived` (aside of hiding `doSomethingWithX`) it can always be used instead of `Base` (and behave exactly as `Base`), can't it?

Comment: @DmitryJ: Yeah the compiler won't care. It's more about what your `doSomething` functions actually do, and what properties you want to preserve about your classes. In this exact scenario I'll grant that your function names may imply Liskov substitution is satisfied, but no invariants are given for either class. If it's true that there are no invariants, then you're okay, however I suspect that you're real case *does* have invariants, and that's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of polymorphism, both implementable in C++: static and dynamic. The latter is what you get with virtual functions and pointers to base classes, in which the behaviour is specialized depending on the real type of object pointed to.
The former can be achieved by writing a template, in which your template type is assumed to have certain interfaces. The compiler will then enforce that when instantiating the template, at compile time. You can provide additional enforcement using SFINAE and/or static_asserts to ensure the type used "is a" or rather conforms to the templated interface used by your code. Note there is not really a straightforward way of defining this interface as with a base interface class, aside from the aforementioned methods.

Note that static polymorphism is what you get at compile time. No dynamically chosen types at runtime. You'll need some form of base class for that.